# How can I display Color Profile of every jpeg in a folder?

Tags: color-spaces, batch

I need to find the color profile of every jpeg in a folder so that I can determine which ones I want to edit. Can I batch list them? I do not have Photoshop.

Comment: I am curious as to why the color profile of a photo is the determining factor in whether or not you want to edit the photo.

Comment: I have scraped thousands of images from the web. I am using them for Artificial Intelligence classification. But the program crashes on some of them; I suspect the CMYK ones or some other profile.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`exiftool`](https://exiftool.org/) you should be able to extract the [ICC profile name using](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/ICC_Profile.html):

```
exiftool -icc_profile:ProfileDescription some_file.jpg
```

You can write a loop in a command line script to do this for a set of images.

If you are interested in other parameters of the ICC profile you can use a different tag name (found on the ICC_profile manual page linked earlier) instead of `ProfileDescription`.
You can write `-icc_profile:*` if you want to see all tags.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I installed and ran the exiftool, deleting the (-k). I also used the download for the Windows installer. I run the command line as indicated referring to a specific jpg but I see no output. This will take some time to learn to use this tool.

Comment: I think (not sure) it's possible that your jpg has no embedded icc profile. In that case exiftool will have nothing to show you and you will see no output.